# Bash script pauses after starting program in background with i3blocks

Tags: bash, i3

I'm trying to make a block in i3blocks that will launch Spotify (if it's closed) when I click on it.

It mostly works fine but when Spotify launches the script just stops until Spotify is closed and the block becomes useless.

Also if i reload i3 Spotify will close.

I've tried making Spotify launch in the background (&) and using the disown flag. but the problem keeps happening, I've also tried the same thing in the i3blocks config file (launching the script in the background).

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if pgrep spotify >/dev/null

then

spotifycli --status

case $BLOCK_BUTTON in

1) spotifycli --playpause;;

2) spotifycli --prev;;

3) spotifycli --next;;

esac

else

echo 

case $BLOCK_BUTTON in

1) spotify & disown; sleep 3; spotifycli --play;;

esac

fi
```

Comment: I found the solution, I forgot to redirect spotify's output into /dev/null. and since it gives no EOF the block was stuck reading spotify's output.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I forgot to redirect spotify's output into /dev/null. and since it gives no EOF the block was stuck reading spotify's output.